# Crawler, relative path to absolute path

Tags: asp.net, windows, winforms

I am trying to fetch pages using "httpwebrequest", but the links also have relative path in them like (.../something/, ../.../something/) , i am trying to map them to absolute path, i am not too good at programming, do we have any utility helpers to do the job, any links, articles, tutorials appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var base = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/a/b/c/d.html");
var relative = new Uri(base, "../e.html"); // http://stackoverflow.com/a/b/e.html
```

[Uri(Uri, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91.aspx)
[Uri.AbsolutePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx)